# What are these words or phrases?

Tags: word, visual, rebus

Given below are clues for 4 separate words or phrases. What are those?

**1**   Five letter word

> Having not intended

[image]

**4**

> Go inside Leland

No partial answers please.

Comment: Are they all connected in the end?

Comment: No they are not @hexomino

Comment: Hmm. I thought 1 would have been the easy one.

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I think they are

1

> FLUKE (just using straight definition, not sure if there is more to it)

2

> FIRST HALF STOCK RETURNS (returns on stock from the first half of the year)

3

> TRAFFIC JAM

4

> LE**GO**LAND

Comment: "By some fluke I realized great first half stock returns from a trade my kid made while we were stuck in a traffic jam exiting Legoland" - seems like they're all connected to me

Comment: @hexomino. 1 and 2 are not my intended answers. But your logic is appreciated

Comment: Nope. Starts with a vowel!

Answer (score 1):

The intended answers for 3 and 4 were given by @hexomino.

The intended answers for 1 and 2

> Having no t in tended : ENDED

> @Avi got this one in his comments. Reverse Stock Split

Comment: Ah, number 1 is clever. I haven't come across number 2 before but works perfectly.